# Unique solution of a variational equation in a finite dimensional subspace and ceas Lemma

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces

I am trying to show the following statement:
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $A:H \rightarrow H$ be $K$-Lipschitz continious and $\beta$-strongly monotone and let $f \in H$. (.,.) denotes the scalar product of the Hilbert space $H$. Further let $V$ be a finite dimensional subspace of $H$. The variational equation
\begin{equation}
(\forall y \in V) (Ax,y)=(f,y) ~~\text{has a unique solution}~~  \overline{x_v}.
\end{equation}
Further, the following inequality holds
\begin{equation}
\lVert \overline{x}-\overline{x_v}\rVert \leq \frac{K}{\beta}min_{y\in V}\lVert\overline{x}-y \rVert.
\end{equation}
Here $\overline{x}$ denotes the unique solution of
\begin{equation}
(\forall y \in H) (Ax,y)=(f,y) .
\end{equation}

I know that the existence of the solution $\overline{x_v}$ follows from Lax-Milgram Theorem.Thus, the first part of the statement is clear to me.
However, I am struggling to prove the inequality. I used the continuity and the monotonicity to show that
\begin{equation}
\lVert \overline{x}-\overline{x_v}\rVert ^2 \leq \frac{1}{\beta}\lVert\overline{x}-\overline{x_v}\rVert \lVert A\overline{x}-A\overline{x_v}\rVert \leq \frac{K}{\beta}\lVert\overline{x}-\overline{x_v}\rVert ^2.
\end{equation}
Now I do not understand how I can show that this is also true if I replace $\overline{x_v}$ with $y \in V$.
In addition, I want to deduce Ceas Lemma from the inequality.
Could anyone please help me to show the inequality and to deduce Ceas Lemma?
Thanks!